# Open Sound Control (OSC) in Matlab 64-bit

Tags: matlab, kinect, osc

I have been using oscmex (http://sourceforge.net/projects/oscmex/) to receive Open Sound Control messages in Matlab r2007b from a Kinect via OSCeleton (https://github.com/Sensebloom/OSCeleton) for a while now. It was working on a Windows XP computer with Matlab 32-bit.

I am now trying to get it to work on a Windows 7 computer with no luck. I installed a 32-bit version of Matlab and added the .dll binaries, but all I can receive are empty OSC packets. I have searched forums high and low without finding a solution.  I know that OSC messages are streaming from the Kinect, because OSCeleton sees the calibration pose and I can see changing variable values in GlovePIE (https://sites.google.com/site/carlkenner/glovepie).

My question is, then, is there an easier way to receive OSC messages in Matlab? I found the script to send OSC messages (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31400-send-open-sound-control-osc-messages) but haven't found one to receive. Any suggestions as to why the osc .dll files won't work on a 32-bit version of Matlab running on a 64-bit system?  Would compiling the oscmex sources against 64-bit Matlab work, and could someone help me do that?  There is clearly a disconnect between the OSC client (OSCeleton) and the OSC server (Matlab), but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance!

Matt